# Using Django, the selected option of a dropdown menu is not passed to the server

Tags: jquery, django, drop-down-menu, django-forms, jquery-select2

I'm using `Django` and `jQuery`.

My `forms.py`:

```
CARPET_TYPE = (
    ('', 'Select a carpet type'),
    ('NRM', 'Normal'),
    ('SLK', 'Silk'),
    ('WOL', 'Wool'),
    ('PER', 'Persian')
)


class CalculationForm(forms.Form):
    carpet_types = forms.ChoiceField(initial='', choices=CARPET_TYPE, label='Carpet Types',)

    length = forms.FloatField(min_value=0)

    width = forms.FloatField(min_value=0)
```

My `calculation_form.html`(which is used as `block content` in my `index.html`):

```
    <form action="{% url 'cleaners:pick_up' %}"  method="POST" id="main_form" class="probootstrap-form">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="probootstrap-size-wrap">
      <label for="{{ form.carpet_types.id_for_label }}">{{ form.carpet_types.label_tag }}</label>

      <!-- <label for="id_label_single" style="width: 100%;"> -->
        <select class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control" id="id_label_single" name="dd-carpets"
                style="width: 100%;">
            {% for choice in form.carpet_types.field.choices %}
                <option value="{{choice.0}}" name="{{form.carpet_types.html_name}}">{{choice.1}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
      <!-- </label> -->

     </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <!-- END carpet type row -->

<div class="row carpet-length">
  <div class="col-md meters-column">
    <div class="form-group" id="calc_main">
      <label for="{{ form.length.id_for_label }}">{{ form.length.label_tag }}</label>
      <div class="probootstrap-size-wrap">
        <input type="text" id="length" class="form-control" name="{{ form.length.html_name }}"
               placeholder="Enter the length of your carpet">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END length row -->

<div class="row carpet-width">
  <div class="col-md meters-column">
    <div class="form-group" id="calc_main">
      <label for="{{ form.width.id_for_label }}">{{ form.width.label_tag }}</label>
      <div class="probootstrap-size-wrap">
        <input type="text" id="width" class="form-control" name="{{ form.width.html_name }}"
               placeholder="Enter the width of your carpet">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END width row -->

<input type="hidden" id="service_cost" name="service_cost" value="">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 calculate">
    <input type="submit" id="calculate_btn" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</form> <!-- END form -->
```

and finally my `views.py`:

```
def pick_up(request):
    # If this is a GET request create the calculation form
    if request.method == 'GET':
        calculation_form_pickup = CalculationForm()
    else:
        calculation_form_pickup = CalculationForm(request.POST)

        if calculation_form_pickup.is_valid():
            carpet_type = calculation_form_pickup.cleaned_data['dd-carpets']
            length = calculation_form_pickup.cleaned_data['length']
            width = calculation_form_pickup.cleaned_data['width']
```

Now, when I'm selecting the carpet type and insert the width and length in the form I get an error when `if calculation_form_pickup.is_valid()` is executed that the `carpet_types` field is required. When examining the `POST` data I can see that the `carpet_types` field is not "cleaned". It's as if I haven't selected anything in the drop down menu.

What am I doing wrong?

***EDIT:***
I forgot to mention that this calculator is based on a bootstrap template that's using the `select2` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've given your select a name attribute of "dd-carpets" instead of "carpet_types".